# Selenium + Python: Why am I getting this no attribute error?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

This is the error that is returned in my console:

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_link_text'

When I look at the source code of the site I am using, the link I want is inside of this iframe, although I can clearly see the link and iframe tag are not on separate source pages, so I assume they are actually on the same code. I tried to remove the iframe line but it still didn't work. Am I missing something maybe an import I'm not aware of?

I had to xxx out some of my info here for privacy purposes.

`
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://webaddress.com")

assert "xxx" in driver.title

elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("whostillusesaol@juno.com")

elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("youvegotma!1")

elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.get("https://webaddress.com/page2")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
element = wait.until(EC.title_contains("xxxx"))

assert "xxxx" in driver.title

driver.switch_to.frame("IFramePanelNameHere")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("the link text goes here").Click()
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using Selenium 4.
Selenium 4 does not support `find_element_by_link_text` as well as any other `find_element_by_*` methods.
A new syntax should be used, as following:

```py
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "the link text goes here").click()
```

In the same manner it will be

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "the xpath expression").click()
```

and

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "the css selector expression").click()
```

etc.
Also, the `click()` method is lowercased, not `Click()`

Comment: A lot of the most popular resources online continue to show this deprecated syntax, which is a bummer but to be expected, probably.

Comment: Right. Most tutorials are not being updated.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed the capital C in click. I thought that was in the documentation as well. ReadTheDocs actually has it updated and I used that method before, but then I saw the one I had here in my post on a different documentation that I guess was NOT updated. After testing with this code, it appears that it cannot find the link. I'm going to try swinging to the iframe and see if that works.

Comment: `Click()` with capital `C` is in `C#` :) In Python it is `click()`, lowercased. Anyway, I'm happy I could help. In case you have more questions you are always welcome to ask more